# C++ library added but still unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, dll, c++14, linker-errors

Inside my c++ project I have a folder: "include" with 3 files:
Framework.h , FrameworkRelease_x86.dll ,FrameworkRelease_x86.lib .

I included them as it was stated in microsoft documentation:
[image][image][image]

But i still have errors with methods from Framework.h if I try to use them:

```
#pragma once

// To use the framework define _WINDOWS in project's settings!
#if defined(_WINDOWS)
    #if defined(FRAMEWORK_PROJECT)
        #define FRAMEWORK_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define FRAMEWORK_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define FRAMEWORK_API 
#endif


 

class Sprite;

FRAMEWORK_API Sprite* createSprite(const char* path);
FRAMEWORK_API void drawSprite(Sprite*, int x, int y);

FRAMEWORK_API void getSpriteSize(Sprite* s, int& w, int &h);
FRAMEWORK_API void setSpriteSize(Sprite* s, int w, int h);
FRAMEWORK_API void destroySprite(Sprite* s);

FRAMEWORK_API void drawTestBackground();
```

Errors:

```
unresolved external symbol "class Sprite * __cdecl createSprite(char const *)"; 
unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl run(class Framework *)" ;
unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl drawTestBackground(void)";
```

I tried adding files as it was stated in microsoft guide and some youtube video (I don't think there are many ways of adding libraries in c++ ) but it doesn't see the methods from FrameworkRelease_x86

Here i provide all code for header file "Framework.h"
`

```
#pragma once

// To use the framework define _WINDOWS in project's settings!
#if defined(_WINDOWS)
    #if defined(FRAMEWORK_PROJECT)
        #define FRAMEWORK_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define FRAMEWORK_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define FRAMEWORK_API 
#endif


// Bonus for any found bugs in the framework!

class Sprite;

FRAMEWORK_API Sprite* createSprite(const char* path);
FRAMEWORK_API void drawSprite(Sprite*, int x, int y);

FRAMEWORK_API void getSpriteSize(Sprite* s, int& w, int &h);
FRAMEWORK_API void setSpriteSize(Sprite* s, int w, int h);
FRAMEWORK_API void destroySprite(Sprite* s);

FRAMEWORK_API void drawTestBackground();

FRAMEWORK_API void getScreenSize(int& w, int &h);

// Get the number of milliseconds since library initialization.
FRAMEWORK_API unsigned int getTickCount();

FRAMEWORK_API void showCursor(bool bShow);

enum class FRKey {
    RIGHT,
    LEFT,
    DOWN,
    UP,
    COUNT
};

enum class FRMouseButton {
    LEFT,
    MIDDLE,
    RIGHT,
    COUNT
};

class Framework {
public:

    // no function calls are available here, this function should only return width, height and fullscreen values
    virtual void PreInit(int& width, int& height, bool& fullscreen) = 0;

    // return : true - ok, false - failed, application will exit
    virtual bool Init() = 0;

    virtual void Close() = 0;

    // return value: if true will exit the application
    virtual bool Tick() = 0;

    // param: xrel, yrel: The relative motion in the X/Y direction 
    // param: x, y : coordinate, relative to window
    virtual void onMouseMove(int x, int y, int xrelative, int yrelative) = 0;

    virtual void onMouseButtonClick(FRMouseButton button, bool isReleased) = 0;

    virtual void onKeyPressed(FRKey k) = 0;

    virtual void onKeyReleased(FRKey k) = 0;

    virtual const char* GetTitle() = 0;

    virtual ~Framework() {};
};


FRAMEWORK_API int run(Framework*);
```

`
and game.cpp:

```
`

#include "Framework.h"
#include<iostream>
 
/* Test Framework realization */
class MyFramework : public Framework {
private:
    Sprite* mySprite;

public:
    virtual void PreInit(int& width, int& height, bool& fullscreen) override {
        width = 800; // Set screen width
        height = 600; // Set screen height
        fullscreen = false; // Set fullscreen mode
    }

    virtual bool Init() override {
        // Load a sprite
        mySprite = createSprite("image.png");
        if (mySprite == nullptr) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to load sprite!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    virtual void Close() override {
        // Cleanup
        destroySprite(mySprite);
    }

    virtual bool Tick() override {
        // Draw the sprite at position (100, 100)
        drawSprite(mySprite, 100, 100);
        return false; // Return true to exit the application
    }

    virtual void onMouseMove(int x, int y, int xrelative, int yrelative) override {}

    virtual void onMouseButtonClick(FRMouseButton button, bool isReleased) override {}

    virtual void onKeyPressed(FRKey k) override {}

    virtual void onKeyReleased(FRKey k) override {}

    virtual const char* GetTitle() override {
        return "My Game";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MyFramework framework;
    return run(&framework);
}`
```

Comment: Make sure that `FRAMEWORK_PROJECT` is not defined in your app preprocessor symbols. I say that because your error message looks wrong for an import library. It looks like `FRAMEWORK_API` is wrongly defined as `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Oh, wait a minute, I missed a different path that the macro could have taken. Do you have `_WINDOWS` defined as a preprocessor symbol in your `c/c++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions` ? If it was not it would skip import and define `FRAMEWORK_API` as nothing.  `// To use the framework define _WINDOWS in project's settings!`

Comment: Hi @drescherjm, thanks for your suggestion! I tried adding it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vXEXb-Sibm4PLPjFmmbBK1ArDZ60dVfb/view but it doesn't seem to resolve it. I also updated my post with a header and cpp file but I begin to think that FrameworkRelease is simply broken. Anyway, Thank you very much for response!